# Is JoinPoint.getArgs() ordered?

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

Say I have this method:

```
public void exampleMethod(String myString, Integer myInteger, Object myObject){}
```

If I have an Aspect `@Around` that, and I call `ProceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()` will it always return an array sorted in the order of the signature? Like this?

```
  public void aspectMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();

    args[0]; // String myString?
    args[1]; // Integer myInteger?
    args[2]; // Object myObject?
  }
```

It does seem to be deterministic, at least for the 10 or so times I've run through this scenario. [I can't find anything in the javadocs to say either way](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()).

Comment: It has to be - otherwise how would you know which is which, considering they're all `Object`s? Also, the [source](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj) is available for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the AspectJ JavaDocs are notoriously terse. But for many logical reasons what *Vasan* said is true: **The order of array elements of `JoinPoint.getArgs()` does correspond to the order of method parameters.**

Looking at the code base, you find several indicators that what I said is true, e.g.

- The [`GetInfo` example](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/6d6738cfece6328027916681e67e54225531db38/docs/dist/doc/examples/tjp/GetInfo.java#L38) relies on the same order of arguments for `JoinPoint.getArgs()`, `CodeSignature.getParameterNames()` and `CodeSignature.getParameterTypes()`.
- [`JoinPointImpl`](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/6d6738cfece6328027916681e67e54225531db38/runtime/src/org/aspectj/runtime/reflect/JoinPointImpl.java#L100), the default implementation of the `JoinPoint` interface, copies the original method's parameter array via `arraycopy`, i.e. the order stays unchanged. Why would anyone want to change it anyway?
- [`JoinPointImplTest`](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/6d6738cfece6328027916681e67e54225531db38/runtime/testsrc/org/aspectj/runtime/reflect/JoinPointImplTest.java#L21) explicitly tests the order of arguments and compares the original method's arguments with the joinpoint's ones.

Answer (score 4):

It's always ordered. Knowing that you can even create a map where keys are parameter names and values are parameter values. The order is always same

```
    String[] keys = ((MethodSignature) jp.getSignature()).getParameterNames();
    Object[] values = jp.getArgs();

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0, keys.length).boxed().forEach(i -> params.put(keys[i], values[i]));
```

Comment: OK, so you can convert two matching arrays into a map. But why would the author (who explicitly asked if he could rely on the order) want to make something ordered into something unordered? In some cases it is nice to have a map-like interface for accessing information if the keys have any practical relevance, but this is not one of them. AOP should not rely on parameter names for doing anything. Yeah, you can log them if the compiler settings did not optimise them away from the bytecode in the first place. So why copy information you already have, making the aspect unnecessarily slow?